# Does Clojure's 'into' hold on to head?

Tags: clojure, seq

I have a very large lazy sequence, and I'd like to convert it into a set. I know that the number of distinct elements in the sequence is small, so I'll easily be able to fit the set into memory. However, I may not be able to fit the entire lazy seq into memory. I want to just do `(into #{} my-lazy-seq)`, but it occurred to me that depending on how `into` is implemented, this might pull the whole seq into memory at once.

Will `into` hold on to the head of the sequence as it operates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any increased usage running this (takes a minute or so)

```
user=> (into #{} (take 1e8 (cycle [:foo :bar])))
#{:bar :foo}
```

More precise proof would be to check [the source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6593) for `into`, and we see it's just a fancy call to `reduce`:

```
(defn into
  ([to from]
     ;...
       (reduce conj to from)))
```

If `reduce` holds on to the head, then `into` does. But I don't think `reduce` does that.

Answer (score 3):

Complementing @progo's answer, you can always use

```
(source into)
```

to check the source code of `into` in repl. This can save you some time looking up the lines in the lengthened core.clj.